# Preferred Width is missing in xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, cell

I'm trying to make something like in this guide http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout,
but can't find property for UILabel named Preferred Width

[image: screenshot]

Is it bug or have i done something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a very outdated version of Xcode? You should be using Xcode 7.1 if you wish to learn modern tools and modern iOS development.

Comment: I know , but i have macbook 2006 late :(  unsupported now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find it in that version of Xcode, you can do it in code

```
[label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:200.0];
```